# pragmatic cross platform (and very fast to make it - actually - work) "throwaway" code: which language/tools?

Tags: scripting, filesystems, process, prototyping

my development style brings me to write a lot of **throw-away "assisting" code**,

whether for automatic generation of code parts, semi-automated testing, and generally to build dummies, prototypes or temporary "sparring partners" for the main development; **I know I'm not the only one...**

since I frequently work both under windows and Unicies, I'd like to non-exclusively focus on a **single "swiss army knife"** tool that can work in both the environments with limited differences, that would allow me to do usual stuff like **text parsing, db access, sockets, nontrivial filesystem and process manipulation**

until now under unix I've used a bit of perl and massive amounts of shell scripts, but the latter are a bit limited and perl... despite being very capable and having modules for an incredible array of duties, sincerely I find it too "hostile" *for me* for something that goes beyond 100 lines of code.

***what would you suggest?***

scripting is not a requirement, it would be ok to use more static-styled languages IF it makes development faster (getting programs to actually do their work and possibly in a **human readable state**) and **if it doesn't become nightmarish to handle errors/exception and to adapt to dynamic environments** (e.g. I don't like to hardwire data /db table structure in my code, especially by hand).

I've been intrigued by **python, ruby, but maybe groovy** (with its ability to access the huge class library and his compact syntax) or something else is better suited

thanks a lot in advance!

(meanwhile, on a completely different note, **scala** looks really tempting just for the cleanliness of it, but that's - probably - a completely different story, unless you tell me the opposite...?)

Comment: A bit of a subjective question. Also quite similar to ["which scripting language is best"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70453/which-scripting-language-is-best), ["which scripting language should I choose"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028414/which-scripting-language-should-i-choose)

Comment: it's unfortunate but it has to be subjective, since we are trying to somewhat "people performance using the tool" and not the performance of the tool itself (e.g. http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=all , but about developers who like to think ;) )

Comment: three very useful replies (thanks a lot!), I think I'm going to go the python route even though I suspect that my way of thinking code is much more ruby-like. but as a practical tool, and not as a preferred language, reading your comments, python might suit better my needs. I'll continue to follow this thread, so if anyone wants to add more, I'm eager to read it ;) thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is arguably one of the best choices. Its biggest benefit is that it has a huge built-in library for doing all sorts of stuff. It is also mature, very cross-platform, actively developed, and has many support options (mailing lists, newsgroups, etc).

In addition, it has a built-in GUI toolkit (tkinter) for those times when you need to write a quick GUI to get input from a user or display output from a running process. And if you don't like tkinter, there are other cross-platform GUI toolkits available.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Python.

For me it has a sweet spot of good libraries, documentation, community, cross-platform functionality, and ease of writing/reading.

It fills a similar niche to Perl's, but if you find Perl to be 'hostile' for longer scripts, you will probably like Python, especially when compared to Ruby, which feels more Perl-y, IMHO.

As an aside, all of these are quite easy to just try out - why not do that?

Then you can decide for yourself instead of trusting the questionable wisdom of an online forum (:

Answer (score 1):

I think that Python and Ruby are your best bets, depending on exactly how you think and code.

I personally find Python EXTREMELY readable and its syntax is highly intuitive. I've heard Python described as "pseudo-code plus colons."

On the other hand, once you get around its slightly bizarre syntax, Ruby makes for high-speed development. It's built around DRY principles and convention-before-configuration, which is great for rapid prototyping.

There are other languages--especially Haskell and the Lisp dialects--that can make for super-rapid prototyping, but they don't have as large a supportive community, so there's a shortage in library and discussion supply.